# Read Xlement fully using LinQ

Tags: linq

I have an XElement which I am getting after parsing an xml. This XElement needs to be read only when the need arises so, I have stored it in a list for future use.

I have to read this XElement using Linq.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(DataManager.offeringElements[index].DataElem.ToString());

        var docNode = from dataNode in doc.Descendants("DataLinks")
                      select new
                      {
                          Offering = dataNode .Element("link").Value,
                          linkUrl = dataNode.Element("link").Attribue("href").Value
                      };
```

the Xelement has the following nodes

```
<DataLinks>
      <link href="">a. Management</link>
      <link href="">b. Analytics</link>
      <link href="">c. Development</link>
    </DataLinks>
```

My problem is that I am not able to read all the three nodes.I am able to get only the first node. Where is it going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This should work i.e. Elemenets not Descendants and ensure when selecting new, you are selecting a type of object.

```
public class ObjectType
{
   public Offering {get; set;}
   public linkUrl {get; set;}
}



 var docNode = from dataNode in doc.Elemenets ("DataLinks")
                  select new ObjectType
                  {
                      Offering = dataNode .Element("link").Value,
                      linkUrl = dataNode.Element("link").Attribue("href").Value
                  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this. IMHO, the method syntax looks cleaner then the query syntax. Note that this is untested code.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> seqLinks = doc.Descendants("DataLinks").Single()
   .Descendants("link");

foreach(XElement link in seqLinks)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value is {0}, and href is {1}", 
        link.Value, link.Attribute("href").Value)
}
```